# How to retrieve values of translate3d?

Tags: javascript, css, regex

This question has already been asked before on *StackOverflow*, what is different with mine is that I'd like to be able to retrieve negative values and also be able to retrieve it with another parameter in `transform` which would be `rotateZ(...deg)` in my case.

I've followed another post on how I can get values of translate3d, the suggested code works and it gets the positiv values but not negative ones (the minus sign is missing).

Another problem is that when I add a new paramater nothing works anymore, I'd like to be able to add whatever paramaters and still make it work.

I think this comes from an issue with the Regex, see http://jsfiddle.net/Lindow/3gBYB/81/

**Regular expression :**

```
transform.match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+)), -{0,1}\d+\)|\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))\))/)
```

**Javascript :**

```
function getTransform(el) {
    var transform = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform');
    var results = transform.match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+)), -{0,1}\d+\)|\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))\))/);

    if(!results) return [0, 0, 0];
    if(results[1] == '3d') return results.slice(2,5);

    results.push(0);
    return results.slice(5, 8); // returns the [X,Y,Z,1] values
}

var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var translation = getTransform(slider);

var translationX = translation[0];
var translationY = translation[1];
var absX = Math.abs(translationX);
var absY = Math.abs(translationY);

alert(absX + ' : ' + absY);
```

**HTML/CSS :**

```
<div id="slider"></div>

----

#slider {
-webkit-transform:translate3d(-393px, -504px, 0) rotateZ(30deg);
// remove rotateZ to make it work with positiv values
// number in translate3d may vary from -9999 to 9999
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also found another solution,

**for (HTML) :**

```
<div style="translate3d(-393px, -504px, 0) rotateZ(30deg);">...</div>
```

**do (JavaScript) :**

```
// get translate3d(..px, ..px, 0px) rotateZ(30deg)
function matrixToArray(matrix) {
  return matrix.substr(7, matrix.length - 8).split(', ');
}

function matrix_translate3d(pos) {
  var matrix_list = [];
  matrix = matrixToArray($(pos).css("-webkit-transform"));
  x = matrix[4].replace(/px/gi, '');
  y = matrix[5].replace(/px/gi, '');
  matrix_list.push(parseInt(x));
  matrix_list.push(parseInt(y));
  return matrix_list;
}

var matrix_position = matrix_translate3d(...);
// matrix_position[0], matrix_position[1]
```

Short solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've adapted your JSFiddle answer to provide a solution - updated your regex to allow for negative numbers, and added a method, "rotate_degree", that will calculate the rotation angle from the computedStyle matrix. This value is placed as an integer at the end of the results array.

Solution is on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lymelight/3gBYB/89/

```
function getTransform(el) {
    var transform = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform');

    function rotate_degree(matrix) {
      if(matrix !== 'none') {
          var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
          var a = values[0];
          var b = values[1];
          var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
      } else { 
        var angle = 0; 
      }
      return (angle < 0) ? angle +=360 : angle;
        }

    var results = transform.match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*(?:, -{0,1}\d+\.?\d*)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*)), -{0,1}\d+\.?\d*\)|\(-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*(?:, -{0,1}\d+\.?\d*)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))\))/);


    var result = [0,0,0];
    if(results){
        if(results[1] == '3d'){
        result = results.slice(2,5);
      } else {
        results.push(0);
        result = results.slice(5, 9); // returns the [X,Y,Z,1] value;
      }

        result.push(rotate_degree(transform));
    };
    return result;
}

var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var translation = getTransform(slider);

console.log(translation);

var translationX = translation[0];
var translationY = translation[1];
var absX = Math.abs(translationX);
var absY = Math.abs(translationY);

console.log('TrX: ' + translationX + ', TrY: ' + translationY + ' , Rotation Angle: ' + translation[3]);

alert('TrX: ' + translationX + ', TrY: ' + translationY + ' , Rotation Angle: ' + translation[3])
```